# how to save stderr and stdout to a file in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, stderr, stdin

when i run

```
echo "invalid crt" | openssl x509 -noout -modulus | openssl md5 &>> error.log
```

this show below error

```
unable to load certificate
139903857870496:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

and "(stdin)= d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" content in error.log

I want to save stdin with error (how to save terminal error text into error.log too)

how can i do that ?

Comment: Title is stdout and stderr, text says stdin and stderr. I'm presuming the title is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
echo "invalid crt" | openssl x509 -noout -modulus | openssl md5 &>> error.log
```

the only the stderr of the second openssl command is written to error.log. Use this:

```
echo "invalid crt" | (openssl x509 -noout -modulus | openssl md5) &>> error.log
```

so that both openssl processes are run in a subshell, and the subshell's stderr is redirected together with the stdout to error.log.

Comment: This is bash-specific.  That's not a bad thing (+1 from me, anyway) it's just worth noting for the benefit of, eg, future `tcsh` users reading this question.

Comment: I personally always do >> error.log 2>&1 but I was following the OP's lead here.

Comment: Me too, and that is **also** bash-specific (well, Bourne-flavoured-shell-specific).

Answer (score 0):

Use `cmd &> file.log` :

```
$ blahblah &> /tmp/blah.log
$ echo $?
127
$ cat /tmp/blah.log 
bash: blahblah: command not found
```

To append, use `cmd >>file.log 2>&1`

```
$ wrongcmd >>/tmp/blah.log 2>&1
$ cat /tmp/blah.log 
bash: blahblah: command not found
bash: wrongcmd: command not found
```